# OOTB Workflow SharePoint 2007 error

Tags: workflow, 2007, error, ootb

I have an error in SharePoint 2007. Recently i did domain migration of my SharePoint 2007 server, using content database detach attach migration and running stsadm migrateuser and migrategroup command

The environment:
SharePoint 2007 SP1
Installed Hotfix:

- KB973410
- KB973409
- KB978396
- KB978392

When the user run the OOTB Approval workflow on some list, the user got this error message [image: Error message]

When I search the error log in the log file, i got this error message

> 10/03/2016 11:44:12.04    w3wp.exe (0x0C8C)                           0x0D18  Windows SharePoint Services     Workflow Infrastructure         88xr    Unexpected  WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# 03856c54-82ed-4fab-878f-e918fcefa03c
>   10/03/2016 11:44:12.04  w3wp.exe (0x0C8C)                           0x0D18  Windows SharePoint Services     Workflow Infrastructure         98d4    Unexpected  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: name     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)     at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.LocUtil.GetResourceString(SPWeb web, String resourceId)     at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.ReviewRouting.SetItemMetadata(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.RaiseEvent(DependencyProperty dependencyEvent, Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.LogToHistoryListActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext context)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(Activity activity, ActivityExecutionContext ...
>   10/03/2016 11:44:12.04* w3wp.exe (0x0C8C)                           0x0D18  Windows SharePoint Services     Workflow Infrastructure         98d4    Unexpected  ...executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()

What should i do? The list don't activate the content approval, and the approval workflow already uncheck the post workflow completion